# googlenet testing technique multi-crop with 144 images in caffe

Tags: caffe

In the googlenet's paper: we resized the image to 4 scales where the shorter dimension (height or width) is 256, 288, 320 and 352 respectively, take the left, center and right square of these resized images.

This gives a more accuracy in testing. However, I found in the Caffe that it up to crop 10(4 corner, 1 middle alone with their mirror) images during testing.

Can anyone give any advices or codes that can explain how to do this within caffe??

Comment: you can modify [`upsample`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py#L341) function to do the resizing + cropping.

Comment: This helps, however, is this means that I can not edit the source code in caffe since that this is a pycaffe interface?